# R shiny - update UI layout using output$"variable"

Tags: r, shiny, eval

Is it possible to reference the shiny UI by way of variable names?

I.e. Say I have as list of countries and for each country I wish to create a UI table output during a loop.

Instead of writing out for each country: `output$America <- renderTable(...` and `output$England <- renderTable(...` etc. I would rather want to put this in a loop and do `output$temp_country <- renderTable(...`.

I am assuming if this is possible one would be using `assign` and/or `eval`?

Comment: try `lapply(list_country,function(i) output[[i]]<-renderTable(...))` and add `observe` if `list_country` is changed  into one session

Comment: see [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35285244/how-to-generate-datatableoutput-dynamically-by-reading-the-csv-files-in-a-loop)

Comment: @Batanichek Seems to be working, you can post this as an answer thansk vm

Comment: @Batanichek, after further testing I am running into an issue. During the loop I use your code above to "programmatically" output tables to the UI. The problem is that all tables are overwritten somehow and contain the same data (that being the data for the last country in the loop)??

Comment: You do it in `for` or in `lapply`? Dont know why but result will be different.

Comment: I do `for (list_country in countries) { (...) lapply(list_country, function...)}` but this seems to overwrite the data in all tables with the data from the last country. This shouldn't be happening I agree :(

Comment: Show all code of your `for` or may be your not need `for` simply  `lapply(countries, function...)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103494/discussion-between-gmarais-and-batanichek).